# ckEditor - Error when I try to ck.setMode('source'); followed by ck.setMode('wysiwyg');

Tags: ckeditor

I have a very difficult situation (for me). I have created a directive for ckEditor. Actually it's the same as I see in many different places on the web. This works most of the time.  However I had to do this to make it work 100% of the time:

```
ngModel.$render = function () {
    if (typeof ngModel.$modelValue != 'undefined') {
        if (ngModel.$modelValue != null) {
            ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            }, 1000);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                ck.setMode('source');
                ck.setMode('wysiwyg');
            }, 1000);
        }   
    }
};
```

Note the lines:

```
ck.setMode('source');
ck.setMode('wysiwyg');
```

This works but gives an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined ckeditor.js:299
CKEDITOR.editable.CKEDITOR.tools.createClass.proto.attachListener ckeditor.js:299
CKEDITOR.editable.CKEDITOR.tools.createClass.proto.setup ckeditor.js:304
k ckeditor.js:589
(anonymous function)
```

Can anyone give me some advice on what might be happening and why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

And if you try this way is it better?

```
ck.setMode('source', function() {
    ck.setMode('wysiwyg');
} );
```

If yes, then the problem was caused by the fact that those methods are asynchronous. They cannot be executed one by one, but you've got to wait until they're done, so they accept a callback which is then executed.

See [`editor.setMode` docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setMode).

PS. [`editor.setData`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData) is asynchronous too.